# Simple way to find the exact address / transaction by the part of the address / transaction hash?

Tags: transactions, addresses

Imagine I have only a part of the address, for example, `0xa2793n`. The rest of the address is unknown. Is there any indexer, that stores this information in any suitable format, so I can find the list of "used" addresses?

1. I know, that the way geth / parity stores the blockchain data doesn't allow such queries. So most likely I need some third party indexer software which maintains an SQL table with the addresses.
2. Also I know that there's a huge amount of theoretically correct addresses with the same beginning, so this software should only do a search in already used addresses.

The same question for transaction hash. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that Etherscan has an autocomplete feature for address search, check the screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

Still not sure if there are any existing solutions for transactions search.

Answer (score 1):

You can write SQL query using LIKE syntax with wildcard character %.

```
SELECT *
FROM ethereum.transactions
WHERE TO_ADDRESS LIKE '0xa2793n%'
```

[See it in action](https://app.flipsidecrypto.com/velocity/queries/d57e21e5-9523-4793-8073-eaa631ed49db) on Flipside.

Answer (score 0):

It does autocomplete on etherscan but only when you write 7 or more of the first digits as I can see.

Is there a way/place to get full suggestions of addresses starting with only the first 6 digits or less?

Comment: It is better to create a new question if you have further doubts.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/70884)